# How to know if a .beam file is compiled with debug_info?

Tags: erlang

I see that I need to compile an `.erl` file with`debug_info` parameter to make it possible to debug it in the debugger.

When I try to debug a `.beam` file in the debugger, I always see that the file has no debug information and can not be opened.

> ** Invalid beam file or no abstract code: "/erlang-debug/myapp.beam"

I suspect it can be that I compile the files in a wrong way.
I tried all the possible way but still no luck and I feel like files are compiled without debug_info.

One of the simplest examples I used is mentioned on [Erlang documentation page](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/debugger/debugger_chapter.html):

```
% erlc +debug_info module.erl
```

Is there a way to know if some specific `.beam` file is compiled with debug_info or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use the [`beam_lib:chunks/2` function](http://erlang.org/doc/man/beam_lib.html#chunks-2) to check the beam file for an abstract code chunk of non-zero size. For example, given a beam file named `x.beam`, you can perform this check from a Linux/UNIX/OS X shell as shown below (note that the `$` is my shell prompt, and I broke this across multiple lines to make it easier to read here but you could put it all on a single line as well — it works either way):

```
$ erl -noinput -eval 'io:format("~s\n",
[case beam_lib:chunks(hd(init:get_plain_arguments()), ["Abst"]) of
    {ok,{_,[{"Abst",A}]}} when byte_size(A) /= 0 -> "yes";
    _ -> "no" end])' -s init stop -- x.beam
```

This examines the beam file for a chunk with the id `"Abst"` and checks that its associated binary data is of non-zero size. If so, it prints `yes`, else it prints `no`.

Below is an example of using it, where we first compile with debug info, check the beam file, then compile without debug info, and check it again:

```
$ erlc +debug_info x.erl
$ erl -noinput -eval 'io:format("~s\n",
[case beam_lib:chunks(hd(init:get_plain_arguments()), ["Abst"]) of
    {ok,{_,[{"Abst",A}]}} when byte_size(A) /= 0 -> "yes";
    _ -> "no" end])' -s init stop -- x.beam
yes
$ erlc +no_debug_info x.erl
$ erl -noinput -eval 'io:format("~s\n",
[case beam_lib:chunks(hd(init:get_plain_arguments()), ["Abst"]) of
    {ok,{_,[{"Abst",A}]}} when byte_size(A) /= 0 -> "yes";
    _ -> "no" end])' -s init stop -- x.beam
no
```

Answer (score 6):

You have access to all the compilation option using the module_info function. To make a test on the debug info flag, you can use the proplists function to extract the information:

```
1> O = fun(M) ->               
1> Comp = M:module_info(compile),      
1> Options = proplists:get_value(options,Comp),
1> proplists:get_value(debug_info,Options)     
1> end.                                        
#Fun<erl_eval.6.50752066>
2> c(p564).
{ok,p564}
3> O(p564).
undefined
4> c(p564,[debug_info]). 
{ok,p564}
5> O(p564).             
true
6>
```